# boot2docker workflow for building an image

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am using Windows and trying to find the most efficient process (from the human perspective) for building a Docker image from a Dockerfile.  The documented way of using Docker on Windows is to use boot2docker to effectively use Docker under a VirtualBox VM.  It seems that boot2docker is just a convenient way to start that VM and SSH into it.

Once in my Docker VM, I cannot find any mapped directories.  I have found no boot2docker options to mount a directory from the host.  The only thing I can find in the documentation is a [section about using Samba](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#folder-sharing) for the Windows host to mount the boot2docker's share.  This is backwards from what would be convenient.

**My Question:  What is the prescribed workflow for using Docker (and specifically, building Docker images) under Windows?**

I must be missing something, as at the moment I see no benefit of using boot2docker.  It seems far easier to fire up a Vagrant-built VM with Docker installed on it, where a directory for my current project is already mapped.  While this doesn't allow for sharing the VM among multiple projects, it certainly makes things more convenient.

What am I missing?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The boot2docker project recently added a feature that lets you do what you want. Make sure you update to the latest.

In the [boot2docker README](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker) the section on  "VirtualBox Guest Additions" mentions that it will now automatically mount your C:/Users directory into the boot2docker VM.

So you should be able to say `docker run -v /Users/myusername/projectname:/src blah blah` and that newly launched docker container will see your project in `/src`.